# How do I obtain updates on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: updates

I've used Ubuntu desktop before but not the server. On the desktop the update manager automatically checks for updates (and allows them to be installed) but how do we do this on the server version?

Answer (score 1):

If you want upgrades automated, you can set up automatic upgrades using:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

Answer (score 0):

type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

type in your password

That should do it.